# If I have system of n equations (any equations in general) with n variables can I always solve it?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

If I have system of n equations (any equations in general) with n variables can I always find all the solutions or prove that there are no such a solutions ? If it's true is there such theorem ?

Comment: Cramer's formula for linear equation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule.

Comment: $x+y=1; x+y=2$ are inconsistent ...

Comment: what kind of equations you have got?

Comment: non linear equations?

Comment: @MarkBennet In this case I can prove that it has no solution, so I will solve it, because to solve system of equations means to find all solutions or to prove that there are no of them.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I mean in general. Is n equations enough for solving system with n variables ?

Comment: @Atmos I meant any equations, not only linear.

Comment: What do you mean by "find"?  Can you "find" the solution to a general quintic polynomial?

Comment: Yes, there are no general solution, you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, if the OP presents his question like here, he is exposed to be downvoted...

A good question would be (for example).

Let $(S)$ be  a system of $n$ algebraic equations in $n$ complex unknowns. Can we know if $(S)$ admits at least one solution.

Using any Grobner basis software, the answer is yes if $n$ and the degrees of the equations are small. More precisely, if the Grobner basis is not reduced to $[1]$, then there is at least one complex solution of $(S)$; the problem is to find such a basis although it is very complicated.

For example, assume that $n=4$ and the $4$ equations are of degree $4$ with respect to the $4$ variables; we obtain a result in $\approx 20"$. In the generic case, according to Bezout, there are $4^4=256$ solutions.

When the underlying field is $\mathbb{R}$, the problem is much more complicated.